# Characterize some counting functions

Tags: combinatorics

```
Apologies for the uninformative title, feel free to amend.
```

Let $A$ be any infinite set. Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Is there a simple characterization the functions

$$\displaystyle f:{A\choose n}\to{\mathbb N}$$

such that for some $B\subseteq A$

$$f(a)=|a\cap B|\ \textrm{ for every }\ a\in {A\choose n}$$

The set $B$ above is uniquely determined by $f$ (right?). Can we easily obtain it from $f\ $?

EDIT: As an example, you can think of $A={\mathbb N}$ and as $B$ the set of even numbers, the set of prime numbers, etc. (but the question is general). I need a property that characterize these functions without mentioning $B$ but only sets of cardinality $a$. (I want a first-order property in the proper language.)

Comment: Please edit the question to include a few examples of such functions, with the (or a)  $B$ for each.

Comment: you mean a finite set $B$? otherwise you always can take $B=A$

Comment: I'm not sure what would qualify as a 'simple characterization', hence I can't address that part of your question.

Comment: @StefanMesken Of course you may not not to say: $\exists B$.... You may quantify over sets of cardinality bounded by some function of $n$. (I'm aware this is a bit vague. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The set $B$ above is uniquely determined by $f$ (right?). Can we easily obtain it from $f\ $?

The answer to both questions is positive:

1. case: There is some $a \in {A \choose n}$ such that $f(a) = 0$. Then
   $$
   B = \{ b \in \mathbb N \mid f(\{b\} \cup a \setminus \{ \min a \}) = 1 \}.
   $$
2. case: Otherwise there is some $a \in {A \choose n}$ such that $f(a) = n$. Then
   $$
   A \setminus B = \{ b \in \mathbb N \mid f(\{b\} \cup a \setminus \{\min a \}) < n \}
   $$
   and $B = \mathbb N \setminus \left( A \setminus B \right)$.

edit: Note that $A$ can be read of easily from $f$ -- so it's appearance as a parameter isn't necessary.

---

Right now I don't have time to carefully check this but I think the following might characterize such functions:

Let $f \colon {A \choose n} \to \mathbb N$ be a function such that

- $\forall a \in {A \choose n} \colon f(a) \le n$,
- $\forall k \in \mathbb N \forall a \in {A \choose n} (f(a) = n-k \Leftrightarrow \exists b \in {a \choose k} \forall c \in {A \setminus b \choose n-k} f(b \cup c) \le n-k$

Let
$$
B = \{ x \in A \mid \forall y \in A \forall a \in {A \setminus\{x,y\} \choose n} f(a \cup \{x\}) \ge f(a \cup \{y\}) \}
$$
Then
$$
f(a) = |B \cap a |
$$
for all $a \in {A \choose n}$.

Comment: As written, the answer assumes $A\subseteq{\mathbb N}$. (But it is clear how to generalize it.)

Comment: @PrimoPetri Oh, yeah. I saw $\mathbb N$ in your edit and hence assumed this was part of your question. But, as you've said, the answer doesn't rely on $A \subseteq \mathbb N$ at all. Instead of $\min a$ take any element of $a$ and replace $\mathbb N$ with $A$ everywhere.

Comment: @PrimoPetri You may want to try to prove or refute my suggestion in the edit. I'm not sure that I'll get back to that today myself. I'd suspect that it won't quite work but it should at least serve as a good starting point for a characterization.

Comment: The idea sounds correct. Tomorrow I'll check it again and accept. Thank you.